# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update&ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate

**this is my pojo class**

> package com.sathya.entity;
>
> public class Customer  {  private String customerId;  private String
>   customerName;     private String location;        public Customer()   {}
>     public Customer(String customerId)  {       this.customerId=customerId;
>     }   public Customer(String customerId,String customerName,String
>   location)     {       this.customerId=customerId;
>         this.customerName=customerName;         this.location=location;     }   public
>   String getCustomerId() {      return customerId;  }   public void
>   setCustomerId(String customerId) {        this.customerId = customerId;   }
>     public String getCustomerName() {       return customerName;    }   public
>   void setCustomerName(String customerName) {       this.customerName =
>   customerName;     }   public String getLocation() {       return location;    }
>     public void setLocation(String location) {      this.location =
>   location;     }   public String toString()    {       return
>   "Customer["+customerId+","+customerName+","+location+"]";     } }

**and my client program is**

```
>         package com.sathya.test;
>     
>     
>     
>     import org.hibernate.Session;
>     import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
>     import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>     import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
>     
>     import com.sathya.entity.Customer;
>     
>     public class InsertCustomer {
>     
>       public static void main(String[] args) 
>       {
>           Configuration config=new Configuration();
>           config.configure("com/sathya/config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
>           SessionFactory factory=config.buildSessionFactory();
>           Session session=factory.openSession();
>           Customer cust=new Customer();
>           cust.setCustomerName("sathya");
>           cust.setLocation("Hyd");
>           Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
>           session.save(cust);
>           tx.commit();
>           session.close();
>           factory.close();
>       }
>     
>     }
```

*

while trying to execute the program getting errors like ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."CUSTOMER"."CUSTOMERID")

*

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ID either manually or by an automated strategy. You use Oracle, you can use sequences.

Comment: You call the cust.setCustomerID manually or in the hibernate mapping file setup the entity to use an oracle sequence